# What does it mean by "A total order,$T$, $⪯$ is said to be compatible with the partial order $R$ if $aRb$ implies a $⪯$ b"?

Tags: relations, order-theory

In this definition:

A total order, $T$, $⪯$ is said to be **compatible** with the partial order $R$ if $aRb$ implies a $⪯$ b

---

There are 2 parts I am confused about.

The 1<sup>st</sup> part: "with the partial order R if $aRb$ implies a $⪯$ b"

The 2<sup>nd</sup> part: "A total order $⪯$ is said to be **compatible**"

---

Is the 1<sup>st</sup> part referring to the ordered pairs in $T$ or $R$?

IE are they saying

For  **every** $(a,b)$$∈$$T$, $(a,b)$$∈$$R$  such that a $⪯$ b? OR

**every** $(a,b)$$∈$$R$ is such that a $⪯$ b

---

As for the 2<sup>nd</sup> part, I have no idea.

Which total order are they suddenly referring to?

Are they just saying there **exists some** total order?

---

Apologies if the question isn't clear, I tried to pinpoint what I am not clear about?

Comment: This is a definition not a theorem

Comment: @QED Thank you,edited it

Comment: A simple (and typical) example: on the positive integers, let $T$ be the usual (linear) ordering and let $aRb$ mean "$a$ divides $b$". I think it is more common to say "$T$ extends $R$" or "$T$ is a refinement of $R$" rather than "compatible with" but it's the same notion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never heard called that *compatible*.
From that definition,, it just means that, as a set of ordered pairs, $R$ is a subset of $\preceq$.
In this situation, it is common to say that $\preceq$ is an extension of $R$.

Related with that, and of possible interest, is the [Szpilrajn extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szpilrajn_extension_theorem).

---

Regarding your conjectures, the second one, about the first part is the correct one, that is, if $a R b$ then $a \preceq b$ (but not necessarily the converse, unless $R$ is already a total ordering).

Comment: Maybe you might have heard "consistent", the MIT video at 53:04 minute at shorturl.at/eEGLM uses that definition.


If I am not wrong, can I then say "A total order, $T$, $⪯$ is said to be **compatible/consistent** with the partial order $R$ if for every $aRb$ implies $aTb$ (replaced the a$⪯$b part here)"?

Comment: @Leon I suppose you can. There are always different terminologies. When I say that it is more common, that mean that in my experience that's what I've heard call to that relationship between orders (indeed, I think it was the only one), and I suppose that if you search information with that keyword, you're more likely to find what you want. Now, in different contexts, it might make sense to use a different term. But in pure order theory, I think that extension is the right one, or at least the common one.