# Should a partial order and total order be related in the context of the "condition" specified in the relation?

Tags: relations, order-theory

I think using examples would convey my question the fastest.

---

Let there be a set $A = \{ 1,2,3,5,10 \}$. Let $R$ be relation such that $a | b$.

Note that in this case $a | b$ is what I mean by "*condition*" which I mentioned in the question

---

Thus $R= \{ (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (1,10), (2,10), (5,10) \}$

One possible total order $T$ would be $T= \{ (1,2), (1,10) \}$ since $1,2,10$ are comparable,ie ($1$⪯$2$⪯$10$) and is partial order.

Both $T$ and $R$ are related by the same *condition*, $a | b$... right?

---

But then my school showed that another possible total order $T$ to be $1 ≺ 2 ≺ 3 ≺ 5 ≺ 10$ ie $T= \{ (1,2), (1,3),...(2,3),(2,5)... (2,10), (5,10) \}$

But how is $2|3$ or $2|5$? Is the condition no longer $a | b$?

---

My question essentially boils down to the title. So can the partial and total order not have the same "*condition*" at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: the condition (that is to say, the *relation* itself) is different in the second case: it's simply the usual $\le$.

Nothing prevents us to consider two different relations on the same set. Nevertheless the chain $1,2,3,5,10$ is *not a chain* with respect to the first relation.

Note that though these are two different relations, they have a connection, namely the first one is *included in* the second one, meaning that $a|b\implies a\le b$ (at least for positive integers).

Comment: Yes, that's the point. This is related to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873385/what-does-it-mean-by-a-total-order-t-⪯-is-said-to-be-compatible-with-the-p) from the same user.